# IFRAME response interpreted as a file by IE6

Tags: iframe, file-upload, internet-explorer-6

I'm getting a strange behavior in IE6 and I need some help figuring it out.

I add the following DOM elements to the end of my document body using javascript:

```
<IFRAME id="qq-upload-handler-iframe0" style="DISPLAY: none" src="javascript:false;" />

<FORM method="post" target="qq-upload-handler-iframe0" encType="multipart/form-data" style="DISPLAY: none" action=/AgriShare-AD-Sys/ajaxfileupload?clientId=importSubmissionFromExcelLinkId&qqfile=AB_PTPTA_10358.xls>
  <INPUT type="file" value="AB_PTPTA_10358.xls">
</FORM>
```

Then I submit the form using javascript. The `action` is pointing at a servlet which returns the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 27 May 2011 23:33:48 GMT
Server: Oracle-Application-Server-10g/10.1.3.5.0 Oracle-HTTP-Server
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=b59f0434f57ace32aebc8b6d113c7e48171824e1d157cf99152140657e6c68a5.e34PaNiLaNuPbO0OaN8Rb3aRbN50; path=/AgriShare-AD-Sys
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; charset=ISO-8859-1


f  
{success: true}
0
```

My intention was for `{success: true}` to end up in the body of the iframe, where I can get access to it from a callback I attached using `iframe.attachEvent('onLoad', callback)`. After the callback completes, I remove the form and the iframe, so that this code can be run again on the same page. This actually works, but **never the first time** after loading the page.

The first time I submit that form, IE6 presents me with a "File Download" dialog, asking me to save a file called `ajaxfileupload.xls`. If I save it this file contains `{success: true}`, which should have been placed into the iframe! Also, the callback is never called.

Any subsequent calls, however, work perfectly! The response data ends up in the iframe document body and the callback gets executed.

I compared the packet traces from the first and second attempts, and they are identical, so this must be a browser issue. Why does IE6 want to save the response into a file the first time?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

I just tried the same thing with Tomcat, and the problem has disappeared. The response from Tomcat looked like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Sat, 28 May 2011 00:13:32 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1

f
{success: true}
0
```

Still need to figure out why it's not working on Oracle though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to explicitly set the `content-type` in my servlet to `text/html`.

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
```